# how to get synonym value from entities ibm watson conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog, watson

i have work-space in www.ibmwatsonconversation.com 
in this work-space i have an entity of automotive_and_vehicles
in this entity have a value of vehicle brand
this value have many synonyms like opel isuzu bmw ford bently ... (30 synonyms) 
like it showed in this two pic
[entities+vehicle brand,synonyms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXCVh.jpg)

I succeed to get the entity and value in java code but when i want to get the synonym value i can't 
this is the output script=>
[script+output pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0IvP.jpg)

Comment: It's very difficult to read your table as it's not rendering the way you intend. Could you edit so that the table is clearer? Also it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: sorry, i changed the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.literal` property to get the exact text that was recognized as the detected entity. E.g. `<?@automotive_and_vehicles.literal?>` in your example.